# Unable to run ccm cli (Cassandra Cluster Manager) on mac

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

I am trying to run ccm [node] cli on mac but am getting the errors below.
I am using cassandra v2.2.0 and ccm 2.0.3.

```
11:32:32: ~/opt $ ccm node1 cli
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ccm", line 72, in <module>
    cmd.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccmlib/cmds/node_cmds.py", line 338, in run
    self.node.run_cli(self.options.cmds, self.options.verbose, self.cli_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccmlib/node.py", line 634, in run_cli
    os.execve(cli, [common.platform_binary('cassandra-cli')] + args, env)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
os.execve(cli, [common.platform_binary('cassandra-cli')] + args, env)
```

It's trying to execute the `casssandra-cli` command, but `cmm` can't find it.

You say you're using Cassandra 2.2.0. In this version of Cassandra, the CLI utility was removed. If you want, you can use version 2.1.9, the last version where this tool is included.

Anyway, the CLI utility is **deprecated**. It's recommended to switch from `Thrift` and `CLI` to `CQL` and `cqlsh`.

See these references:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/reference/referenceStorage_r.html

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-community-2-2-0-is-ready-for-download

Comment: Yep, but does this mean that CCM does not work with Cassandra 2.2.0?

Comment: No, it works, only the cli command doesn't work because it's not in the Cassandra bin directory

Comment: Do you know where I can find the equivalent commands - e.g. 'list' for a table?

Comment: This page list the `cqlsh`commands for Cassandra 2.2  http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCommandsTOC.html. In the menu at the top of that page (the CQL option), you can find the reference for other versions. For example, I think the equivalent of `list`is `describe`. However, `cqlsh` is a little different, since it's a higher abstraction than the `cassandra-cli`.

Comment: Which command? `describe`? http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/describe_r.html